# javascript document.getElementById is not working

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Do you know why this easy javascript is not working? It is working in
Firefox, Chrome isnt working in IE Safari and Opera. 
Can you help me?
It seems to document.getElementById has some problem in IE, Safari and Opera. Why?

```
   <form name="formular" action="test.php">
      <select id="testMenu" name="testMenu" onChange="testOptions()">
        <option id="X2" value="2">2</option>
        <option id="X3" value="3" selected>3</option>
        <option id="X4" value="4">4</option>                        
      </select>     

      <select id="nextMenu" name="nextMenu">
        <option id="B1" value="1">B1</option>
        <option id="B2" value="2">B2</option>
      </select>
   </form>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       var choose_option =3;

       function testOptions() {
       var choose_option = document.getElementById("testMenu").selectedIndex+2;

       if (choose_option == 4){
          document.getElementById("B2").style.display="none";
        }else{
          document.getElementById("B2").style.display="block";  
        }
    }   
    </script>
```

Comment: What happens? Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors...it is strange but lets try http://www.maxibet.net/test.php - when you choose number 4 in first selection you should have in second selection only one option

Comment: improper debugging. You shoudl have first tested to see if `document.getElementById("B2")` was working separate from using `.style.display = value.`, which would have shown you that `document.getElementById("B2")` is working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think `getElementById`, specifically, isn’t working? The problem is more along the lines of not being able to apply `display: none` to `<option>` elements. The easiest fix would probably be to set `disabled` for it:

```
document.getElementById("B2").disabled = choose_option === 4;
```

If you want it to really be gone, that would be done by removing it:

```
var nextMenu = document.getElementById("nextMenu");
var b2 = document.getElementById("B2");

function testOptions() {
    var choose_option = document.getElementById("testMenu").selectedIndex + 2;

    if (choose_option === 4) {
        if (b2.parentNode) {
            b2.parentNode.removeChild(b2);
        }
    } else if (!b2.parentNode) {
        nextMenu.appendChild(b2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is right. I'm pretty sure that hiding `<option>s` is not possible with CSS. You'll have to remove them and add them appropriately.

Comment: thanks, disabled is good idea, but not in this situation...I need to hide, not just disable...I have to try use removing, but easier is to hide - remove I will use if there is no possibity to solve it by hiding

Comment: minitech OK I tried removing and it have started working in each browser except IE. Do you know why? Do you have any solution for IE as well?

Comment: @jvku: Which version of IE? Are there any errors in the console? Try logging the value of `document.getElementById("testMenu").selectedIndex`.

Comment: IE 8.0 and no console problem, lets try in IE... http://www.maxibet.net/test.php Is it working?